# cannot import pybrain module in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pybrain

I followed the exact documentation in [here](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/installation.html)
but after that importing produces the following error. I am using windows 7 and python 2.7. I have already installed scipy and matplotlib.
The error that I get is as follows:

```
>>> import pybrain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.__init__ import *
  File "pybrain\structure\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.__init__ import *
  File "pybrain\structure\modules\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.structure.modules.gate import GateLayer, DoubleGateLayer, Multi
plicationLayer, SwitchLayer
  File "pybrain\structure\modules\gate.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pybrain.tools.functions import sigmoid, sigmoidPrime
  File "pybrain\tools\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd, logm, expm2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 174, in <m
odule>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>

    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <modul
e>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scipy requires installing numpy+mkl. You can install this lib from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy